# What is difference between Mockito.spy(List.class) and Mockito.spy(new ArrayList())?

Tags: java, junit, mockito

The first test case is failed due to IndexOutOfBoundsException. The second one is successful. What is difference between Mockito.spy(List.class) and Mockito.spy(new ArrayList())?

```
@Test
public void thenReturnWithSpy1() {

    List<String> list = Mockito.spy(List.class);

    when(list.get(0)).thenReturn("abc");

    assertEquals("abc", list.get(0));
}

@Test
public void thenReturnWithSpy2() {

    List<String> list = Mockito.spy(new ArrayList());

    when(list.get(0)).thenReturn("abc");

    assertEquals("abc", list.get(0));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Mockito spies delegate calls to the actual underlying object. This is true even when stubbing. So :

```
when(list.get(0)).thenReturn("abc");
```

already does an invocation on the spy.

`new ArrayList()` is an empty list. Calling `list.get(0)` on it, even during stubbing, will result in a `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

When you use a spy on a class, there is no actual instance to delegate to, and as `List` is an interface with no implementation for `get()`, Mockito will not delegate to any 'actual code'.

So, it's the stubbing that fails.

There is an easy solution, though. By using the `doReturn()` style of stubbing you avoid actual invocations during stubbing, at the expense of reading a little less fluently.

```
doReturn("abc").when(list).get(0);
```